# S4S Error saving a form

Tags: sitecore-forms, salesforce-connect

Upon trying to save a S4S form it gives S4S submit action failed error message. 
In Sitecore logs, I get the following error:

p.s. S4S = Sitecore CMS to Salesforce CRM

```
13996 17:41:04 INFO  FuseIT.S4SMapping.SitecoreExperienceForms.SaveActions.S4SSubmitActionForExperienceForms - Get fields for Case
13996 17:41:04 INFO  FuseIT.S4SMapping.SitecoreExperienceForms.Utility.SalesforceUtility - GetExistingSalesforceEntity() -  Generated SOQL query: SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Individual_Email__c='myemailaddress@gmail.com'
13996 17:41:04 ERROR Error: FuseIT.Sitecore.SalesforceConnector.Services.SalesforceServiceFoundation - Errors in upsert results. Failed Records Count =1
13996 17:41:04 ERROR Error: FuseIT.S4SMapping.SitecoreExperienceForms.SaveActions.S4SSubmitActionForExperienceForms - Exception occured when running 'S4S Generic Submit Action' for Sitecore Experience forms.
Exception: FuseIT.Sitecore.SalesforceConnector.Exceptions.SalesforceCreateException
Message: Error StatusCode:INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY
Failed to save 1 new sObject(s)

0:Error  INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY - Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: 01244000000gQp1AAE
Successfully saved 0 records.
Source: FuseIT.Sitecore.SalesforceConnector
   at FuseIT.Sitecore.SalesforceConnector.Services.SalesforceServiceFoundation`1.ced211b9e93280afa98d0e2a14b4ce31f(List`1 c232126cbfe9bed4f2041480823f825f9, sObject[] c8026294143c8618ebf219c4598adfb1a, SaveResult[] c22fe2b9ff66d39fd5254e687b13b027b)
   at FuseIT.Sitecore.SalesforceConnector.Services.SalesforceServiceFoundation`1.InsertEntities(List`1 entities)
   at FuseIT.Sitecore.SalesforceConnector.Services.SalesforceServiceFoundation`1.Save(List`1 entities)
   at FuseIT.Sitecore.SalesforceConnector.Services.SalesforceServiceFoundation`1.Save(EB entity)
   at FuseIT.S4SMapping.SitecoreExperienceForms.SaveActions.S4SSubmitActionForExperienceForms.SaveSFEntity(SalesforceSession sfSession, List`1 formFieldValueList, Item mappingItem, String sfObjectName, String entityId, Boolean includeAnalytics)
   at FuseIT.S4SMapping.SitecoreExperienceForms.SaveActions.S4SSubmitActionForExperienceForms.S4SSubmitActionWithoutAnalytics(SalesforceSession sfSession, List`1 formFieldValueList, Item mappingItem, String sfObjectName)
   at FuseIT.S4SMapping.SitecoreExperienceForms.SaveActions.S4SSubmitActionForExperienceForms.Execute(UpdateContactData data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
```

Any insights or advice on solving this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you login to your salesforce account to see if you account is active.

Comment: Make sure that 01244000000gQp1AAE is assigned to the RecordType of the right object. It seems that you are referencing the incorrect record type id and try to save in a wrong field.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `01244000000gQp1AAE` is a valid RecordTypeID for Case records then it is likely that the API user that is configured against S4S doesn't have access to it based on either their profile or granted permission sets.

Check the the S4S API user has sufficient permissions to create a new Case record with the given record type Id.

See [How is record type access specified?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=permissions_record_type_access.htm&type=5)